# Slow performance of MacBook Air 2017

Tags: ssd, memory, performance, cpu

I am using MacBook Air (MBA) 2017 model. Everything was very fine till 8th Aug 2022. Suddenly, my MBA started to perform very slow. Everything is working, but performance is soo slow that it is difficult to open safari and email id. I have done everything mentioned on the various forum, and discussed the issued thrice with apple support centre, but things are same. Lastly, I erased entire disk, and installed MacOS from the internet. But, still everything is same. After erasing the entire disk, I have also reset SMC, NVRAM, verified disk multiple times, but no effect on the performance. I have already check safe mode, but this has no effects. Through inspection of activity monitor, I have realised that apps are still taking high CPU usage, which might causing the problem. But why applications are using high cpu is not known.

I have realised that there are many people who are facing the same issue with the MacBook. One of my friend replaced the SSD, but still performance did not improved as expected.

```
[System configuration: 
MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
Processor: 1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB][1]
```

I have also attached EtreCheck report, and screenshot of the CPU usage as well as memory usage.

Kindly provide working solution for the problem.

Thanks

[image: CPU Usage]
[image: Memory Usage]

```
    EtreCheckPro version: 6.7 (67009)
Report generated: 2022-08-10 19:20:03
Download EtreCheckPro from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 11:27
Performance: Poor

Problem: Computer is too slow

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  Heavy CPU usage - Some processes are using an unusually high amount of CPU.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  SSD too slow - SSD is showing poor performance.
  No Time Machine backup - Time Machine backup not found.
  Apps crashing - There have been numerous app crashes.
  Limited permissions - More information may be available with Full Disk Access.

Hardware Information:
  MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
  MacBook Air Model: MacBookAir7,2
  1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 (i5-5350U) CPU: 2-core
  8 GB RAM - Not upgradeable
    BANK 0/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1600  
    BANK 1/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1600  
  Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 657

Video Information:
  Intel HD Graphics 6000 - VRAM: 1536 MB
    Color LCD 1440 x 900

Drives:
  disk0 - APPLE SSD SM0128G 121.33 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes) 
  Internal PCI 5.0 GT/s x4 Serial ATA
    disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 121.12 GB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 121.12 GB (Shared by 6 volumes)
        disk1s1 - Macintosh HD - Data (APFS) [APFS Virtual drive] (21.92 GB used)
        disk1s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (268 MB used)
        disk1s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (1.12 GB used)
        disk1s4 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (1 MB used)
        disk1s5 (APFS) [APFS Container] (15.41 GB used)
          disk1s5s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) [APFS Snapshot] (15.41 GB used)
        disk1s6 - Update (APFS) (778 KB used)

Mounted Volumes:
  disk1s1 - Macintosh HD - Data [APFS Virtual drive]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Data
    Used: 21.92 GB
    Shared values
      Size: 121.12 GB
      Free: 82.28 GB
      Available: 82.52 GB

  disk1s2 - Preboot [APFS Preboot]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Preboot
    Used: 268 MB
    Shared values
      Size: 121.12 GB
      Free: 82.28 GB

  disk1s4 - VM [APFS VM]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/VM
    Used: 1 MB
    Shared values
      Size: 121.12 GB
      Free: 82.28 GB

  disk1s5s1 - Macintosh HD [APFS Snapshot]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /
    Read-only: Yes
    Used: 15.41 GB
    Shared values
      Size: 121.12 GB
      Free: 82.28 GB
      Available: 82.52 GB

  disk1s6 - Update
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Update
    Used: 778 KB
    Shared values
      Size: 121.12 GB
      Free: 82.28 GB

Network:
  Interface en0: Wi-Fi
    802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
  Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge
  iCloud Status: one pending file

System Software:
  macOS Monterey 12.5 (21G72) 
  Time since boot: About an hour

Notifications:
  EtreCheckPro.app
    one notification

Security:
  Gatekeeper: App Store and identified developers
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled

  Antivirus software: Apple

System Launch Daemons:
  [Not Loaded]  37 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  209 Apple tasks
  [Running]  133 Apple tasks
  [Other]  2 Apple tasks

System Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded]  15 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  195 Apple tasks
  [Running]  146 Apple tasks

Backup:
  Time Machine Not Configured!

Performance:
  System Load: 1.54 (1 min ago) 6.35 (5 min ago) 16.55 (15 min ago)
  Nominal I/O usage: 0.39 MB/s
  File system: 120.30 seconds (timed out)
  Write speed: 575 MB/s
  Read speed: 931 MB/s

CPU Usage Snapshot:
  Type Overall
  System: 22 %
  User: 41 %
  Idle: 37 %

Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:
  Process (count) CPU (Source - Location)
  system_profiler (2) 78.32 % (Apple)
  QuickLookSatellite 71.05 % (Apple)
  MTLCompilerService (20) 48.60 % (Apple)
  WindowServer 43.94 % (Apple)
  mediaanalysisd 40.22 % (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:
  Process (count) RAM usage (Source - Location)
  com.apple.WebKit.WebContent (10) 1.34 GB (Apple)
  EtreCheckPro 566 MB (Etresoft, Inc.)
  MTLCompilerService (21) 516 MB (Apple)
  system_profiler (2) 473 MB (Apple)
  QuickLookUIService (4) 177 MB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:
  Process (count) Input / Output (Source - Location)
  com.apple.WebKit.Networking 299 KB / 321 KB (Apple)
  mDNSResponder 110 KB / 83 KB (Apple)
  cloudd 8 KB / 4 KB (Apple)
  apsd 5 KB / 7 KB (Apple)
  netbiosd 2 KB / 2 KB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Energy Use:
  Process (count) Energy (0-100) (Source - Location)
  com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService (3) 15 (Apple)
  system_profiler (2) 12 (Apple)
  trustd (4) 9 (Apple)
  Safari 6 (Apple)
  WindowServer 4 (Apple)

Virtual Memory Information:
  Physical RAM: 8 GB

  Free RAM: 41 MB
  Used RAM: 4.76 GB
  Cached files: 3.20 GB

  Available RAM: 3.24 GB
  Swap Used: 0 B

Software Installs (past 60 days):
  Install Date Name (Version)
  2022-08-10 macOS 12.5 (12.5)

Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
  2022-08-10 15:14:31 ContextStoreAgent Crash
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetContext.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ContextStoreAgent

  2022-08-10 09:18:08 bluetoothd Crash (6 times)
    Executable: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd


End of report
```

Comment: Is the cooling fan running hard?  This looks like an issue I have on the MPB (2018) with overheating.  `kernal_task` pretends to take up CPU cycles in an effort to let it cool down.  I primarily run into the problem while running a second monitor.

Comment: @MarcelWilson Thanks, but there is no such issue of overheating. These are screenshots after restarting the app.

Comment: restarting the macbook*